Django Bokeh App does not render the chart, console says: bokeh-3.4.0.min.js:616 [bokeh 3.4.0] could not set initial ranges
I'm trying to render a Bokeh chart on my html template view but unsuccessfully, any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.
This is the view class:
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.embed import components
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from .models import FinancialInstrument, HistoricalData

class Offline(View):
    '''Responsable to indicate the way to the Offline Analysis '''  
    form_class=HugeStatForm
    template_name='charts/offline.html'
    api_key = 'I0T0AM1MH4Y4X0DC'

    def get(self, request):
        user=request.user
        historical_me=FinancialInstrument.objects.all()
        form = self.form_class(historical_me=historical_me)
        #instruments = FinancialInstrument.objects.all()
        
        retrive=HistoricalData.objects.all()
        get_symbol=retrive.filter(instrument__symbol="BTUSD")
        x_values = [key.date for key in get_symbol]
        y_values = [float(key.opening_price) for key in get_symbol]
        source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(dater=x_values,pricer=y_values))
        plot = figure(title="New title",
                      x_axis_label="Date", y_axis_label="Max Price", x_axis_type="datetime")
        plot.line(x='dater',y='pricer', source=source,line_width=1)

        script, div = components(plot)
        if user.is_authenticated:
            return render(request,self.template_name, {'form':form,'script':script, 'div':div,})
        return redirect('home')

This is a peace of my template view:
<script src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-3.4.0.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="col mx-0 px-0 d-flex justify-content-start">
   <!-- Bottom Section Content -->
   <!-- Chart goes here -->
   {{ script | safe }}
   {{ div | safe }}
</div>

When i load the page, it appears a blank chart and the console from the browser in the Developer mode says "bokeh-3.4.0.min.js:616 [bokeh 3.4.0] could not set initial ranges"
Here i have the list of the installed apps on my virtual environment:
Package                   Version
------------------------- -----------
aiohttp                   3.9.3
aiosignal                 1.3.1
alpha-vantage             2.3.1
appdirs                   1.4.4
asgiref                   3.8.1
asyncio                   3.4.3
attrs                     23.2.0
autobahn                  23.6.2
Automat                   22.10.0
beautifulsoup4            4.12.3
blinker                   1.7.0
bokeh                     3.4.0
bokeh-django              0.1.0
bottle                    0.12.25
certifi                   2024.2.2
cffi                      1.16.0
channels                  3.0.5
charset-normalizer        3.3.2
click                     8.1.7
clr-loader                0.2.6
colorama                  0.4.6
constantly                23.10.4
contourpy                 1.2.1
cryptography              42.0.5
cycler                    0.12.1
daphne                    3.0.2
dash                      2.9.3
dash-bootstrap-components 1.5.0
dash-core-components      2.0.0
dash-html-components      2.0.0
dash-table                5.0.0
Django                    5.0.4
django-ranged-response    0.2.0
dpd_components            0.1.0
Flask                     3.0.3
fonttools                 4.51.0
frozendict                2.4.1
frozenlist                1.4.1
html5lib                  1.1
hyperlink                 21.0.0
idna                      3.6
incremental               22.10.0
itsdangerous              2.1.2
Jinja2                    3.1.3
kiwisolver                1.4.5
lightweight-charts        1.0.20
lxml                      5.2.1
MarkupSafe                2.1.5
matplotlib                3.8.4
multidict                 6.0.5
multitasking              0.0.11
mysqlclient               2.2.4
nest-asyncio              1.6.0
numpy                     1.26.4
packaging                 24.0
pandas                    2.2.1
peewee                    3.17.1
pillow                    10.3.0
pip                       23.2.1
proxy_tools               0.1.0
psycopg2                  2.9.9
pyasn1                    0.6.0
pyasn1_modules            0.4.0
pycparser                 2.22
pyOpenSSL                 24.1.0
pyparsing                 3.1.2
python-dateutil           2.9.0.post0
pythonnet                 3.0.3
pytz                      2024.1
pywebview                 5.0.5
PyYAML                    6.0.1
requests                  2.31.0
service-identity          24.1.0
setuptools                69.2.0
six                       1.16.0
soupsieve                 2.5
sqlparse                  0.4.4
tenacity                  8.2.3
tornado                   6.4
Twisted                   24.3.0
twisted-iocpsupport       1.0.4
txaio                     23.1.1
typing_extensions         4.11.0
tzdata                    2024.1
urllib3                   2.2.1
webencodings              0.5.1
Werkzeug                  3.0.2
xyzservices               2024.4.0
yarl                      1.9.4
yfinance                  0.2.37
zope.interface            6.2


Please, help me make my chart render.

This is usually caused by one of two things: you have no data at all initially in your plot (you'll need to make sure that the plot starts with some data so that default auto-ranging has something to work with, or else explicitly set your own range bounds up front), or: you are using string ("categorical") coordinates without also configuring a categorical factor range (are your date values acutal real datetime objects, or are they mistakenly date strings? If so you need to convert to real datetime values)

Thank you @bigreddot, i had already fixed my issue. It was exactly as you said, even thought i had a "date" object, i needed to have a time object and use the "datetime.combine()" function to make it run.
